# How to delete rows faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sub to delete a row when certain criteria is met. However, I find it taking way too much time to run. Is there any way I could make this run any faster?

```
'This sub deletes the row that has any of the following values

Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, lastrow&, value$
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Product Qty")
lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    value = ws.Cells(i, 2).value
    ' Check if it contains one of the keywords.
    If (value Like "*VOI*" _
        Or value Like "*SLOC*" _
        Or value Like "*NCM*" _
        Or value Like "*RTS*" _
        Or value Like "*VND*" _
        Or value Like "*DFFC*" _
        Or value Like "*STOR*") _
        Then
        ' Protected values found. Delete the row.
        ws.Rows(i).delete
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Copy your range to an array. Manipulate the array to your needs and than transpose it back to your range. There are a few things you will have to cater for but working with arrays is always faster than rows in an excel file

Comment: There are some simple optimisation steps. Screenupdating, and calculationmode manual are those. If you are looking for significant improvements you should join your rows to be deleted and then delete only the joined array. As the most expensive are interactions with your worksheet, so you should strive to limit those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that make your code faster:

1. Read your data into an array and loop through that array instead of a range. Looping through arrays is faster than looping through ranges.
2. Collect all the rows you want to delete in a range variable `RowsToDelete` using the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) and delete them all at once in the end.

Note that I recommend not to use `Value` as a variable name as this could easily confuse with the `.Value` property of a range.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Product Qty")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'read data into array
    DataArr() As Variant
    DataArr = ws.Range("B1", "B" & LastRow).value

    Dim ChkVal As String

    'we collect all rows in a range using union
    Dim RowsToDelete As Range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To UBound(DataArr, 1)
        ChkVal = DataArr(iRow, 1)
        ' Check if it contains one of the keywords.
        If (ChkVal Like "*VOI*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*SLOC*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*NCM*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*RTS*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*VND*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*DFFC*" _
            Or ChkVal Like "*STOR*") Then
            ' Protected values found.
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then 'first row
                Set RowsToDelete = ws.Rows(iRow)
            Else 'all following rows
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, ws.Rows(iRow))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'delete all rows
    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then RowsToDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple wildcard criteria, you can do it by an autofilter also:

- put filter criteria in a range (on a separate sheet)
- use the range for an autofilter
- delete all rows

The criteria-rows are OR-combined and can be placed anywhere on a different worksheet:

[image: Range with filter criteria]

By following, above critera defines all rows to be *deleted*:

```
Private Sub DeleteRowsFast()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, fs As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set fs = Sheets("FilterSheet")
    ws.UsedRange.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=fs.Range("Filter1"), _
        Unique:=False
    ws.Rows("2:1000000").Delete Shift:=xlUp  ' delete visible rows
    ws.ShowAllData
End Sub
```